# Split sequence dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of sequences like this

```
dput(df)
structure(list(val = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("{36415},{36415}", 
                           "{36415},{85610}", "{36415},{9904}", "{85025,36415}", "{85610},{36415}", 
                           "{8872},{36415}"), class = "factor")), .Names = "val", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                -6L), class = "data.frame")

df
              val
1  {36415},{9904}
2 {36415},{85610}
3   {85025,36415}
4 {36415},{36415}
5 {85610},{36415}
6  {8872},{36415}
```

Notice the 3rd row above. The first row says there is a sequence item 1 followed by item 2 in different rows. The 3rd row says item1 and 2 belong to same row in the sequence

I want to break this data frame into columns like this

```
col1        col2
36415       9904
36415       85610
85025,36415 NA
36415       36415
...
```

Notice how the 3rd row of the data frame is.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes with `strsplit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
df = separate(df, col = val, into = c("col1", "col2"), sep = "\\},\\{", fill = "right")
df[] = lapply(df, gsub, pattern = "\\{|\\}", replacement = "")
df
#          col1  col2
# 1       36415  9904
# 2       36415 85610
# 3 85025,36415  <NA>
# 4       36415 36415
# 5       85610 36415
# 6        8872 36415
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. We can separate the column and then remove any `{` or `}`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  separate(val, into = c("col1", "col2"), sep = "\\},\\{", fill = "right") %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("\\{|\\}", "", .)))
df2
#          col1  col2
# 1       36415  9904
# 2       36415 85610
# 3 85025,36415  <NA>
# 4       36415 36415
# 5       85610 36415
# 6        8872 36415
```

Comment: the 3rd column has the element 85025,36415 in the same column

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner with `extract` from `tidyr`. This uses capture groups to specify the column patterns:

```
library(tidyr)

extract(df, "val", c("col1", "col2"), regex = "\\{([\\d,]+)(?:\\},\\{)?([\\d,]+)?\\}")
```

or with `str_match` from `stringr`. This uses the exact same regex:

```
library(stringr)

data.frame(str_match(df$val, "\\{([\\d,]+)(?:\\},\\{)?([\\d,]+)?\\}")[,-1])
```

**Result:**

```
         col1  col2
1       36415  9904
2       36415 85610
3 85025,36415  <NA>
4       36415 36415
5       85610 36415
6        8872 36415

           X1    X2
1       36415  9904
2       36415 85610
3 85025,36415  <NA>
4       36415 36415
5       85610 36415
6        8872 36415
```